# Stopping the timeline sound on a loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, timeline, audio

I'm working on a `as3` player which loads `swf` like videos/chapters, inside them I have images and a level where a `sound starts to play at frame 1`.

I'm trying to stopping the sound of the loaded `swf` when I change it with a previous or later loaded file but nothing seem to work.

**I've tried this:**

```
loaded_swf.stop();
SoundMixer.stopAll();
media_container.removeChild(loaded_swf);
```

**I've tried also this:**

```
loaded_swf.stop();
var snd_transform:SoundTransform = SoundMixer.soundTransform;
snd_transform.volume = 0;
SoundMixer.soundTransform = snd_transform;
SoundMixer.stopAll();
media_container.removeChild(loaded_swf);
```

**And this:**

```
loaded_swf.stop();
var snd_transform:SoundTransform = loaded_swf.soundTransform;
snd_transform.volume = 0;
swf.soundTransform = snd_transform;
SoundMixer.stopAll();
media_container.removeChild(loaded_swf);
```

the timeline sound works without notice the `SoundMixer` method.
Does exists some way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little recursive function that will silence all of the audio in a movieclip. If you're using timeline sounds, this should shut them up.

```
public function stopAllSounds(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    var mute:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.0);
    mc.soundTransform = mute;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < mc.numChildren; ++i)
    {
        var m:DisplayObject = mc.getChildAt(i);
        if(m is MovieClip) stopAllSounds(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: soundTransform is actually a property of Sprite, so you should mute every Sprite you find but you would only iterate on the childs of movie clips.

Answer (score -1):

Editing James' answer to make sure really everything is stopped (not just MovieClips):

```
public function stopAllSounds(sp:Sprite):void
{
    var mute:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.0);
    sp.soundTransform = mute;

    var mc : MovieClip = sp as MovieClip;
    if(mc != null)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < mc.numChildren; ++i)
        {
            var m:DisplayObject = mc.getChildAt(i);
            if(m != null) stopAllSounds(m);
        }
    }
}
```